# jQuery Fading in a Child Element When Parent Element is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-traversal

I am trying to fade in a child element when a parent element is clicked using `jQuery`, but `.children()` does not seem to be accomplishing what I am trying to do.

I attempting to make the `<h2>` element fade in when the `<h1>` element is clicked.

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h2').hide();
    $('h1').bind('click', function() {
        $(this).children().fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<h1>
Visible Parent
    <h2>
    Hidden Child
    </h2>
</h1>
```

A `JSFiddle` of the code can be fouind here: http://jsfiddle.net/jHkAB/5/

**SOLVED:**

By separating the `<h1>` and `<h2>` elements and then using `.next()` to select the element after the `<h1>` element, the next element fades in when the element before it is clicked.

A `JSFiddle` of the code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/jHkAB/16/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heading elements (`h1`, `h2`, etc.) [cannot be contained in each other](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements), so your HTML is normalized by the browser and becomes this:

```
<h1>
Visible Parent
</h1>
    <h2>
    Hidden Child
    </h2>
```

That is why you animation won't trigger, because `h2` is not a child of `h1` anymore.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Is there a way that I could still choose the first element after the <h1> tag if the <h1> and <h2> elements are separated?

Comment: @KevinGurney You could use `next()` like in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/jHkAB/16/).

Comment: You could also use `.siblings()` as well!

Comment: @eivers88 Yes. Reading the jQuery docs is a good idea. I still find some methods that I forgot about or simply haven't used before :).